# SignalR Transport Error even after removing SingalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, transport

Some Times ago, I tried SignalR in a project. After this test, I remove SignalR and all of his depedencies, I removed the Hub class I made etc.

But I still get an error message when I start my application:

> No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a
>   different transport or none at all for auto initialization.

I looked at Web.config, Global.asax etc. but I didn't found a reference to SignalR, an I still get this error message.

Is there someone knowing a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: this error comes from the javascript client - clean up you html/js files because this is where the client is trying to connect from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to browser link.

After shutting it, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

May be entirely stating the obvious, but have you done a clean and build? Sometimes dlls dont get built by visual studio as there was a bug in older versions for incremental builds! (Vs2008 i had this but unsure where it got fixed). Just wanted to make sure you've covered all bases!

Comment: I tried yes. But it didn't change anything.
I still get the same issue.

Thank you.